# Where's the method?

Tags: java

My source:

```
private static HashMap<String, Class<?>> mapLogic = new HashMap<String,Class<?>>();

mapLogic.put("s", Packet1.class);
mapLogic.put("a", Packet2.class);

public abstract class Packet { 
    public abstract void get(ChannelBuffer buffer);
    public abstract void send(ChannelBuffer buffer);
}
```

and

```
public class Packet1 extends Packet{

    @Override
    public void get(ChannelBuffer buffer) {
    }


    @Override
    public void send(ChannelBuffer buffer) {
    }

}


public class Packet2 extends Packet{

    @Override
    public void get(ChannelBuffer buffer) {
    }

    @Override
    public void send(ChannelBuffer buffer) {
    }

}
```

`mapLogic.get("s").newInstance().get()`   <--- get or send not available

How can I get these methods?

Comment: You need to specify a parameter.

Comment: Try `mapLogic.get("s").newInstance().get(null);`

Comment: @Legend not available method  get send

Comment: I just noticed the error in the `HashMap`, @ruakh pointed this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
private static HashMap<String, Class<?>> mapLogic = new HashMap<String,Class<?>>();
```

to this:

```
private static HashMap<String, Class<? extends Packet>> mapLogic =
    new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Packet>>();
```

so that the expression `mapLogic.get("s")` will have type `Class<? extends Packet>`, and the expression `mapLogic.get("s").newInstance()` will have type `Packet`.

The way you have it now, the expression `mapLogic.get("s")` has type `Class<?>`, and the expression `mapLogic.get("s").newInstance()` has type `Object`. The compiler has no way to tell that the actual instance will have runtime-type `Packet1` or `Packet2`, so it doesn't know what the `get` and `send` methods are supposed to be.